# #VALUES! while using IF and OR together

Tags: arrays, excel

I have the File as following format

Name Number Position 
A             1      
B                  2      
C                  3      
D                  4

Now on `position A3` , I applied `=IF(B2=1,"Goal Keeper",OR(IF(B2=2,"Defender",OR(IF(B2=3,"MidField","Striker")))))`
 But it giving me an error #value! 
Looked up at google, and my formula is correct.
What i basically want it 
1- Goalkeeper 2-Defender 3-Midfield 4-Striker
Yes the other way is to to just filter the number and copy paste the text 
But I want to do it using formula and want to know where did I go wrong.

Comment: Are we missing some other context? **Why** is this strictly limited to `IF` and `OR` functions? *Homework maybe?*

Comment: @urdearboy exactly. This is HW , using IF OR , or easier would be VLOOK UP like the user posted before or more simple would be , just filtering cell and copying pasting the text with entire text and so on.

Comment: The easiest way would be **=CHOOSE(B2,"Goal Keeper","Defender","Midfield","Striker")** and there is paxdiablo's **If** version. In both cases if you change the value in cell **B2**, the value in **A3** will change accordingly. Is that the functionality you need? I don't see how or why to implement **OR**? So I'm guessing you need something else (a different functionality). Try to figure out what it is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are actually tasked with solving the problem by using the `IF` and `OR` function within the same equation, this is the only way I can see how:

```
=IF(OR(B1=1, B1 = 2, B1 = 3, B1 = 4),IF(B1 = 1, "Goal Keeper", IF(B1 = 2,"Defender",IF(B1 = 3,"MidField","Striker")))
```

If `B1` does not equal 1-4, the `OR` function will return `FALSE` and completely bypass all of the nested `IF` statements.

Comment: Thank you this works. M def gonna ask teacher about it. Like there r easier way to acheive the same result. Vlook up and all. But since we r studying IF OR , may be she gave us to do this.

Comment: read the other answer and think about what or() returns when the condition tested is true ie text...

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem lies with the expression (for example):

```
OR(IF(B2=3,"MidField","Striker"))
   |  \__/ \________/ \_______/ |
   |  bool   string    string   |
   \____________________________/
               string
```

The `OR` function expects a series of *boolean* values (true or false) and you're giving it a *string* value from the inner `IF`.

You don't actually *need* the `or` bits in this specific case, the `if` is a full `if-else`. So you can just use:

```
=IF(B1=1,"Goal Keeper",IF(B2=2,"Defender",IF(B2=3,"MidField","Striker")))
```

This means that `B1=1` will result in `"Goal Keeper"`, otherwise it will evaluate `IF(B2=2,"Defender",IF(B2=3,"MidField","Striker"))`.

Then *that* means that, if `B2=2`, it will result in `"Defender"`, otherwise it will evaluate `IF(B2=3,"MidField","Striker")`.

Finally, that means the `B2=3` will result in `"MidField"`, anything else will give `"Striker"`.

The only situation I can envisage when `OR` would come in handy here would be when two different numbers were to generate the same string. Let's say both `1` *and* `4` should give `"Goalie"`, you could use:

```
=IF(OR(B1=1,B1=4),"Goalie",IF(B2=2,"Defender","MidField"))
```

---

Keep in mind that a more general solution would be better implemented with the Excel lookup functions, ones that would search a table (on the spreadsheet somewhere) which mapped the integers to strings. Then, if the mapping needed to change, you would just update the table rather than going back and changing the formula in every single row.

Comment: Assuming there are 4 text for each number, is there any way to include `OR` using IF to create the data I want? I must implement IF , OR any how. Likewise, the other user also told vlookup way, yes I can easily sort the data as per vlookup or just by filtering the number cell and copying pasting the text .

Comment: @ReverseAngle, you would only want to use `or` if there were multiple values that could result in the same text. Since that's not the case, it's easier to do it with just `if` on its own.